# Animating gradient view works in preview canvas but weird behavior on device

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, gradient, linear-gradients

This is what I used to create an animating gradient view

```
struct AnimatedBackground: View {
   @State var start = UnitPoint.leading
   @State var end = UnitPoint.trailing
   
 
   
   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
   let colors: [Color] = [ .blue, .red ]
   
   
   var body: some View {
       
       
       LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors), startPoint: start, endPoint: end)
           .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3).repeatForever())
           .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
               
              
   
                self.start = .topLeading
               self.end = .bottomTrailing
               
           
               self.start = .bottom
               self.end = .top
           
            
               self.start = .bottomLeading
               self.end = .topTrailing
               
               
               self.start = .leading
               self.end = .trailing
               
        
               self.start = .topLeading
               self.end =  .bottomTrailing
               
               
               self.start = .top
               self.end = .bottom
               
               
               self.start = .bottomLeading
               self.end = .topTrailing
               
            
               self.start = .leading
               self.end = .trailing
               
            
               
           }).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }
}
```

It works properly when I view it in the preview canvas on Xcode but when I run it on device not only does the gradient not animate but the *view itself* moves on and off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just do a [`.animation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:)) without providing the `value`, SwiftUI will animate *everything*. This includes position changes, for example when the device goes from portrait to landscape.

To *only* animate what you want (the start and end points), just pass one of them in for the `value`.

```
.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3).repeatForever(), value: start)
```

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Gradient position animates on device rotation along with start and end points, leaving white space on screen] | [image: Gradient position does not animate on device rotation, only the start and end points animate] |

Comment: how did you put the xcode simulator video in your stackoverflow answer>

Comment: @MichealS.Bingham great, can you click the green checkmark to accept the answer?

Comment: The video is actually a gif - I recorded it using QuickTime, then used [Gifski](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Gifski) to convert it into gif. I sometimes also use my project [ProgressGif](https://github.com/aheze/ProgressGif), which lets you convert videos to gifs with progress bars.

Comment: How do I make it swirl in one direction instead of swaying back and forth? @aheze .

Comment: I edited my question so you could see my attempt

Comment: @MichealS.Bingham that's not very related to this question, maybe [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?